# Deploying Datalore to Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, datalore

I have been trying for weeks to deploy [DataLore by JetBrains](https://datalore.jetbrains.com/) to Heroku with no success. I seem to be able to push the web service to Heroku with variables set to read the database URL / password from a Heroku Postgres add-on based on suggestions from their support team (see [here](https://datalore-forum.jetbrains.com/t/deployment-using-docker-and-heroku/1493)). But I just end up with an application error when I try to access the site after deployment that says:

> - 03:32:57.974 [31mWARN [0;39m [main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext   Failed startup of context
>   o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@76494737{datalore.xml,/,file:///tmp/jetty-0_0_0_0-8080-datalore_war-_-any-7211023058917384221/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/opt/datalore/jetty/webapps/datalore.war}

Jetbrains has not been much help as they claim they don't officially support Heroku and both Heroku and Docker are definitely outside my wheelhouse. Does anyone have any experience deploying DataLore (or another web app where you only have access to a docker-compose file, not the actual Dockerfile)? Or barring that, has anyone managed to get DataLore up and running on their local machine (I'm on an M1 macbook)? I'm completely stuck and cannot get this up and running, and unfortunately our internal infrastructure team doesn't have the cycles right now to assist so I'm on my own here.